# Parameters issue on PLSQL Procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I've have an issue while running a PL SQL stored procedure.

It says it need parameters but it is defined without anyone.

I've tried to run as this `execute SP_LIST_PRICE_BWI;`

Here is the procedure declaration:

`create or replace PROCEDURE SP_LIST_PRICE_BWI (P_ERROR_CODE OUT VARCHAR2,P_ERROR_TEXT OUT VARCHAR2,P_DATA_TEXT OUT VARCHAR2 )`

I will really appreciate if you could help me out.

Regards,
Nicolás.

Comment: The procedure defined **three** out parameters. You need to provide some (PL/SQL) variable where the procedure can put the results into

Comment: In the procedure those three out parameters are defined and used.
What do you mean by provide parameters?

Comment: The signature of the procedure is a **specification**. In this case it specifies three output parameters. This means you need to **assign** three matching variables when you call the procedure.

Comment: Thank, indeed your assistance make me understand what is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call a procedure without providing the variable names for `OUT` parameters.

Either you use bind variables

```
VARIABLE v_ERROR_CODE VARCHAR2
VARIABLE v_ERROR_TEXT VARCHAR2
VARIABLE v_DATA_TEXT  VARCHAR2

EXECUTE SP_LIST_PRICE_BWI(:v_ERROR_CODE ,:v_ERROR_TEXT, :v_DATA_TEXT);
```

**OR** 
declare variables with proper size and pass them

```
DECLARE
v_ERROR_CODE VARCHAR2(5);
v_ERROR_TEXT VARCHAR2(100);
v_DATA_TEXT  VARCHAR2(1000);

BEGIN
 SP_LIST_PRICE_BWI(v_ERROR_CODE ,v_ERROR_TEXT, v_DATA_TEXT);
END;
```